# What's the reason for BUG_ON in __get_vm_area_node?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, vmalloc

Why is this assertion in `__get_vm_area_node`?

```c
static struct vm_struct *__get_vm_area_node(...)
{
    // ...
    BUG_ON(in_interrupt())
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Because someone put it there :P Have you looked at all? What does `in_interrupt()` do? What code is in `__get_vm_area_node()` that doesn't work from interrupts?

Answer (score 0):

I think [the commit that introduced that line](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=52fd24ca1db3a741f144bbc229beefe044202cac) explains it pretty well:

> If `__vmalloc` is called to allocate memory with `GFP_ATOMIC` in atomic
> context, the chain of calls results in `__get_vm_area_node` allocating memory
> for `vm_struct` with `GFP_KERNEL`, causing the 'sleeping from invalid context'
> warning.  This patch fixes it by passing the gfp flags along so
> `__get_vm_area_node` allocates memory for `vm_struct` with the same flags.

```
@@ -160,13 +160,15 @@ int map_vm_area(struct vm_struct *area, pgprot_t prot, struct page ***pages)
    return err;
 }
 
-struct vm_struct *__get_vm_area_node(unsigned long size, unsigned long flags,
-               unsigned long start, unsigned long end, int node)
+static struct vm_struct *__get_vm_area_node(unsigned long size, unsigned long flags,
+                       unsigned long start, unsigned long end,
+                       int node, gfp_t gfp_mask)
 {
    struct vm_struct **p, *tmp, *area;
    unsigned long align = 1;
    unsigned long addr;
 
+   BUG_ON(in_interrupt());
    if (flags & VM_IOREMAP) {
        int bit = fls(size);
```

In short, the following code in that function *could sleep*, and sleeping is not allowed in interrupt context. The `BUG_ON` is added to prevent this kind of problem.